# Import a txt file into excel and each line separates into columns (for a ,' or ,)

Tags: excel, vba

Request help, I do not know how to make this code in vb excel.
I need to import a txt file into excel and each line separates into columns. The separator is the comma, but when it finds a comma followed by a plica ('), the separator is there and not in the comma.

In the example case can not separate between the "77," nor in the "88,"
that is, the field (cell=C1) is between plicas (, '60-77, TEXTO',)

example:

LINE, '123', '60-77, TEXT', '100', '200', 1, -1,1,

LINE, '456', '60-88, TEXT', '100', '200', 1, -1,1,

LINE, '789', 'TEXT', '100', '200', 1, -1,0,

can you help me?

like this in excel.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Workbooks.OpenText makes quick work of this providing you add the correct parameters. The two that seems particularly important for your problem is the comma:=True and textqualifier:=xlTextQualifierSingleQuote.

```
Sub importTXT()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:="c:\test\testcsv.txt", textqualifier:=xlTextQualifierSingleQuote, _
                                comma:=True, Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, Space:=False, other:=False)
    With wb
        'do stuff to the imported workbook here
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: in office 2016 I had to make the following code change. But even so is not expected. Call Workbooks.OpenText and Set wb = ActiveWorkbook